# `helvet` and `moveleft` in resume

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, cv, resume

[image]
[image]

I have several questions about the following code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Medium Length Graduate Curriculum Vitae
    % LaTeX Template
    % Version 1.1 (9/12/12)
    %
    % This template has been downloaded from:
    % http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
    %
    % Original author:
    % Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute (http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/)
%
% Important note:
% This template requires the res.cls file to be in the same directory as the
% .tex file. The res.cls file provides the resume style used for structuring the
% document.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[margin, 10pt]{res} % Use the res.cls style, the font size can be changed to 11pt or 12pt here

\usepackage{helvet} % Default font is the helvetica postscript font
%\usepackage{newcent} % To change the default font to the new century schoolbook postscript font uncomment this line and comment the one above

\setlength{\textwidth}{5.1in} % Text width of the document

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND ADDRESS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{\large\bf John Smith} % Your name at the top

\moveleft\hoffset\vbox{\hrule width\resumewidth height 1pt}\smallskip % Horizontal line after name; adjust line thickness by changing the '1pt'

\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{123 Broadway} % Your address
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{City, State 12345}
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{(000) 111-1111 or (111) 111-1112}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{resume}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OBJECTIVE SECTIONk
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{OBJECTIVE}  

A position in the field of computers with special interests in business applications programming, information processing, and management systems. 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{EDUCATION}

{\sl Bachelor of Science,} Interdisciplinary Science \\
Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute, Troy, NY, expected December 1990 \\
Concentration: Computer Science \\
Minor: Management 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMPUTER SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{COMPUTER \\ SKILLS} 

{\sl Languages \& Software:} 
COBOL, IFPS, Focus, Megacalc, Pascal, Modula2, C, APL, SNOBOL, FORTRAN, LISP, SPIRES, BASIC, VSPC Autotab, IBM 370 Assembler, Lotus 1-2-3. \\
{\sl Operating Systems:} MTS, TSO, Unix. 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PROFESSIONAL EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{EXPERIENCE}

{\sl Business Applications Programmer} \hfill Fall 1990 \\
Allied-Signal Bendix Friction Materials Division, Financial Planning Department, Latham, NY 

\begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt % Reduce space between items
\item Developed four ``user friendly" forecasting systems each of which produces 18 to 139 individual reports. 
\item Developed or improved almost all IFPS programs used for financial reports. 
\end{itemize}

{\sl Research Programmer} \hfill Summer 1990 \\
Psychology Department, Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute 
\begin{itemize} 
\item Performed computer aided statistical analysis of data. 
\end{itemize} 

{\sl Assistant Manager} \hfill Summers 1988-89 \\
Thunder Restaurant, Canton, CT
\begin{itemize}
\item Recognized need for, developed, and wrote employee training manual. Performed various duties including cooking, employee training, ordering, and inventory control. 
\end{itemize} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMMUNITY SERVICE SECTION
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

\section{COMMUNITY \\ SERVICE}

Organized and directed the 1988 and 1989 Grand Marshall Week \\
``Basketball Marathon.'' A 24 hour charity event to benefit the Troy Boys Club. Over 250 people participated each year. 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EXTRA-CURRICULAR ACTIVITIES SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{EXTRA-CURRICULAR \\ ACTIVITIES} 

Elected {\it House Manager}, Rho Phi Sorority \\
Elected {\it Sports Chairman} \\
Attended Krannet Leadership Conference \\
Headed delegation to Rho Phi Congress \\
Junior varsity basketball team \\
Participant, seven intramural athletic teams 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

1. What does `\moveleft.5\hoffset` mean here? Why there is `.5` right after `\moveleft` and why there is no argument after `hoffset`?
2. For `\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{\large\bf John Smith}`, you already `centerline` the name, but why you still want to move it to the left? You want the name to appear in the center, right?

Comment: The default value for `\hoffset` is `1in` and `.5\hoffset` means one half of `\hoffset`.

Comment: @Sigur Got it, what about my second question?

Comment: If you move a little bit to left you get a longer line and then you write the name on its center.

Comment: @Sigur I think my confusion is about why you move a little to the left, you get a longer line. Can you refer me to a website that contains this part of knowledge?

Comment: Well, sorry, maybe I'm not well expressing myself. I don't know why they want to move left but for some reason they want to move some parts outside the left margin. See the `geometry` documentation. http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry

Comment: @Sigur From the typeset pdf, nothing seems to go outside the left margin. I attached the picture in the question.

Comment: Load `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}`

Comment: @Sigur I got it, but why the frame is not in the center, but to the right? This is the reason we need to make the text to the left, because if we just put it in the center, it will appear to the right in the typeset.

Comment: The frame depends on the margins and dimensions of the text area. You can have the same output as the CV using another configuration for the margins without moving it to left. It is just the way how the class was build. Read that documentation.

Comment: See lines starting from 775 in `res.cls`. There it is defined the dimensions.

Comment: @Sigur The default value of `\hoffset` is `0pt`, not `1in`. It is added to the `1in` margin that TeX automatically starts with. In LaTeX, it is not usually changed from this default. LaTeX adjusts the left margin in the outout routine by moving the whole page box to the right by `\oddsidemargin` or `\evensidemargin`. I don't know why `res.cls` bothers with `\hoffset` instead of using the standard LaTeX dimensions.

Comment: @Sigur You should make your comments into an anwser

Comment: @Dan, you're right. I had a confusion and wrote `1in` thinking at the final result, as you said, one inch from the paper margin. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `\hoffset` has default value of `0pt` You can use multiples of it using `<number>\hoffset`, for example, one half of it `.5\hoffset`. Probably in the `res.cls` they changed its value so it makes sense to use some fraction of it.
2. After moving to the left the command `\centerline` is to center the contents of the line (which has length `\linewidth`).

Load the `geometry` package with the `showframe` option and you could see what is happening with respect to the margins.

```
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
```

You'll see that some texts is outside the text area.